# C macro expand in another C macro

Tags: c

I have something like :

```
#define NBR 42
#define THE_ANS_IS theAnsIsNBR
```

Currently the second macro is expand as 'theAnsIsNBR' as expected, but i want it to be expand as 'theAnsIs42' i am not sure if it is even possible !?

Comment: I think we need a canonical duplicate for the `##` operator, as this is quite a common FAQ. Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define Paste(x, y)  x##y
#define Expand(x, y) Paste(x, y)

#define NBR 42
#define THE_ANS_IS Expand(theAnsIs, NBR)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#define _CONCAT(x,y) x ## y
#define CONCAT(x,y) _CONCAT(x,y)

#define NBR 42
#define THE_ANS_IS CONCAT(theAnsIs, NBR)
```

This works because `##` concatenates two tokens. The problem is, they aren't expanded first. But calling another macro on them expands them, therefore you need to nest two function-like macros here.

Comment: thx for the explanation bro.